# How to Sort posts by Vote Count?

Tags: php, sort, rating

Does anyone know how to automatically sort posts by Vote Count?

I am using a plugin called WP Voting where a visitor can vote on a post. The plugin keeps track of how many votes each post has. The author offered some code that would sort them posts in the main blog page and it works, but it unfortunately broke the Category view.

The code is below and it is dropped into the `functions.php`

```
/**
 * SORTS THE POSTS BY VOTE COUNT
 */
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
add_filter('posts_join_paged','edit_posts_join_paged');

    function edit_posts_join_paged($join_paged_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $join_paged_statement = "LEFT JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting ON ".$wpdb-                >prefix."wpv_voting.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID";
    return $join_paged_statement;
}

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
     $orderby_statement = "(".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting.vote_count) DESC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the hooks in a conditional check something like:

```
if (is_home() || is_front_page()){
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
    add_filter('posts_join_paged','edit_posts_join_paged');
}
```

and leave the rest as is.

Comment: Bainternet, thank you for your time! I added that code and it helps the issue of categories not breaking, but the sorting no longer works on the home page. Maybe it doesn't know it's my home page?

Comment: But more importantly, I'm wondering if you might know how to modify this code to work on the home page as it did AND work on the categories. I will gladly paypal you $15 to help me get this working. Please send your paypal info. :)